# Pandas vectorization using all cumulative sum of all previous rows and all following rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

Im trying to convert an excel sheet to Python and 
part of one of the functions is (SUMSQ(K$8:K36)+SUMSQ(K38:K$39)))

this is the sum of squares of all previous rows plus the sum of squares of all following rows
my best attempt is:

```
def SUMSQ(x):
     return ((sum([i**2 for i in x]))-(sum(x)**2)/len(x))

SUMSQ(df1['K']) + SUMSQ(df1.iloc[-1::]['K'])
```

I know I'm not indexing the part of the data frame correctly. Is there a way to index from the beginning of the column to the row above the current position?

Comment: please add the excel sheet and all functions so other people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could use some clarification, but it seems like you want to exclude the current row from the SUMSQ calculation. If so, then the following should work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'k': range(1, 11)})  
for idx in range(len(df)):
    print(SUMSQ(df.loc[df.index != idx, 'k']))
```

Output is

```
60.0
68.88888888888891
75.55555555555554
80.0
82.22222222222223
82.22222222222223
80.0
75.55555555555554
68.88888888888889
60.0
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly the solution I was looking for! Sorry about the vague question